# How to change a variable according to the user, administrator

Tags: php, admin

I have a user table with a column called `id_role`.  All new users are assigned a `id_role` value of `3` by default.

Any users that need higher level privileges, I manually update them to `2` for `administrator` and `1` for `super_admin`.

The problem is that `id_role` is still worth the value of the last registered and I do not understand why.

[image: https://imgur.com/IjEqzq9]

If I do not add a new user `id_role`, it will always be 1 and everyone will log in `superadmin`, if I am adding a new user, `id_role` will be 3 and everyone (even the admin) will log in as a basic user.

Here is my basic code :

```
<?php
session_start();

$Nom = $_POST["Nom"];
$mdp = $_POST["mdp"];
//$id_role = $_POST["id_role"];

try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=azer', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die("acces imlpossible");
}

$st = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM membre WHERE Nom='".$Nom."'")->fetch();
$mangetesmorts = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM membre WHERE id_role");

if (password_verify($mdp, $st['mdp'])) {
    $_SESSION['Nom'] = $Nom;
    $_SESSION['activite'] = $st['activite'];    //$_SESSION['id_role'] = $mangetesmorts['id_role'];
    //var_dump($_SESSION['id_role']);

    //print_r($id_role);
    while ($donne = $mangetesmorts->fetch()) {
        if ($_SESSION['activite'] =='cricket') {
            header("Location: cricket.php");
        } elseif ($_SESSION['activite'] == 'foot') {
            header("Location: foot.php");
        } elseif (($donne['id_role'] == 2)) {
            header("Location: admin.php");
        } elseif ($donne['id_role'] == 1) {
            header("Location: admin_super.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: index2.php");}
        }
   }
```

and that's what I tried after:

```
<?php
session_start();

$Nom = $_POST["Nom"];
$mdp = $_POST["mdp"];
//$id_role = $_POST["id_role"];

try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=azer', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("acces imlpossible");
}

$st = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM membre WHERE Nom='".$Nom."'")->fetch();
$mangetesmorts = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM membre WHERE id_role");

if (password_verify($mdp, $st['mdp'])) {
    $_SESSION['Nom'] = $Nom;
    $_SESSION['activite'] = $st['activite'];
    //$_SESSION['id_role'] = $mangetesmorts['id_role'];
    //var_dump($_SESSION['id_role']);

    //print_r($id_role);
    while ($donne = $mangetesmorts->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['id_role']=$donne['id_role'];
        if ($_SESSION['activite'] =='cricket') {
            header("Location: cricket.php");
        } elseif ($_SESSION['activite'] == 'foot') {
            header("Location: foot.php");
        } elseif ($_SESSION['id_role'] == 2) {
            header("Location: admin.php");
        } elseif ($_SESSION['id_role'] == 1) {
            header("Location: admin_super.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: index2.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks a bit _incomplete_ `SELECT * FROM membre WHERE id_role`

Comment: What should I add to your opinion ?

Comment: a comparison operator and a number.  It's like going to a burger restaurant and saying "I'd like the Whopper with".  My French is rusty, is `$mangetesmorts` something about "eating death"?

Comment: Your query is insecure/unstable because you are writing user-supplied data directly into your query.

Comment: yep xD it would say : it's a very populary insult in France (among young people) I often insult my variables when I can not make them work xD

Comment: for now I'm not really concerned about safety, it's our teacher who will teach us about it. Maybe it is :     SELECT * FROM membre WHERE id_role=1,2,3"

Comment: Well, it is just something that we like to announce so that people can be aware.  For instance if `Charles D'Artagnan` tries to login, your query will break. Not to mention if someone wants to be naughty they can throw injection attacks at it. If you want to write a WHERE condition that includes those three numbers, you will want `WHERE id_role IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: it is the same problem i writed ' $mangetesmorts=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM membre WHERE id_role IN (1,2,3)");'

Comment: @martingenereux I am not permitted to add any non-white space characters while editing.  You need to add a semicolon after `$_SESSION['activite'] = $st['activite']`.  About your code logic... `SELECT * FROM membre WHERE Nom='".$Nom."'"` is already going to be returning `id_role` in the result set, so there is no need to query a second time.

Comment: If `$st` gives you the single row of the user, you will not need to use the while loop; just use `$st['id_role']` and `$st['activite']`  ( I don't see the need to write `$st['activite']` to the `$_SESSION` array.  Is that necessary for a reason that I do not see?

Comment: no, there is no particular reason, I did it a little blind, I did not know that I could use '$ st ['activite']' without putting it in a superglobal SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your block of conditional redirects is based on the second query which does not reference the user that has successfully logged in.  (if that query works at all).

In other words, `while ($donne = $mangetesmorts->fetch()) {` is going to pull all rows from your table, then iterate the only the first row because the redirect will end the script.

Because your first SELECT query is returning the full row of data for the user as the array `$st` just use that to determine the redirect.

```
if (in_array($st['activite'], ['cricket', 'foot'])) {
    header("Location: {$st['activite']}.php");
} elseif ($st['id_role'] == 2) {
    header("Location: admin.php");
} elseif ($st['id_role'] == 1) {
    header("Location: admin_super.php");
} else {
    header("Location: index2.php");
}
```

You can declare whatever `$_SESSION` elements you like, I've left them out of this condition block for clarity/consistency.

Comment: I think I almost understand, I'm supposed to do the 2 requests Name and id_role in the same line? If yes, how ?

Comment: The `*` in `"SELECT * FROM membre WHERE Nom='".$Nom."'"` is going to give you all of the column values for the single user.  (assuming the `Nom` column is Unique -- if not, make it so)  `$st` has all the data you need.  Use `$st['mdp']` to check the password and use `$st['activite']` and `$st['id_role']` to determine the redirect.  Done.  p.s. I also recommend that you check for a successful match in `$st`.  `if (!$st)` then there was no `Nom` match.

Comment: it's works very welle, I did not understand at all that. $ Name. gave me all the info about the user, thank you very much :))